# How do I change the opacity of an image when I hover of my text?

Tags: css, html, image, hover

I am new to HTML and CSS and I have [my own website](http://www.lucafraser.nl).
The problem is that I don't know how to change the opacity when I hover over my text. I want it to become lighter if I'm hovering over my text in the menu on the right. Right now It's only changing when I hover over the image itself, the text changes too, but I want it to both change at the same time and on the same object, so I hover over the text; text changes and images opacity changes.

Here is my code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-image: url(lucafraserProject/images/backgroundImage.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
}
#container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
}
#header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 45px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
#aboutMe {
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 background-color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 2;
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 padding-left: 36px;
 padding-right: 36px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
 float: left;
}
#footer {
 width: 100%;
 color: #333333;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 float: left;
}
.aboutMe {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.h2AboutMe {
 font-size: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.h1Header {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#menuLinks {
 background-color: #FFF;
 height: auto;
 width: 21%;
 float: left;
 padding: 25px 36px;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 2;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 padding-left: 36px;
 padding-right: 36px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
.h2Menu {
 font-size: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#menuRechts {
 background-color: #FFF;
 height: auto;
 width: 21%;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #333333;
 line-height: 2;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-bottom: 25px;
 padding-left: 36px;
 padding-right: 36px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
li {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: -40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 color: #000;
}
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 color: #000;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#menuLinks li ul {
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
}
.marginClassP {
 margin-top: -50px;
}
.marginLeft {
 margin-left: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.mainMenu {
 font-size: 20px;
}
#widespace {
 width: 2%;
 height: 500px;
 float: left;
}
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
body {
}
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
/*1210px = follow me lelijk = new css, tablet device, mobile width = */

.pic {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);;
}
.pic:hover {
 opacity: 0.3;
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>lucafraser.nl</title>
<link href="indexCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <h1 class="h1Header">Welcome</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="widespace"></div>
  <div id="menuLinks">
    <h2 class="h2Menu">Menu</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">Portfolio</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">Results</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">News</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">Blog</span></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><span class="mainMenu">Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="widespace"></div>
  <div id="aboutMe">
    <h2 class="h2AboutMe">Home</h2>
    <p class="aboutMe">I am trying to get this website to work on mobile devices. After that I will continue creating my website and I will be inserting pages with content. Also, I am trying to get the font-type I use to work for everyone so you don't see the ugly standard font-type. Thanks for your patience!<br />Update: The font is working now! I hope it's readable :D</p>
  </div>
  <div id="widespace"></div>
  <div id="menuRechts">
    <h2 class="h2Menu">Follow me</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="lucafraserProject/images/48x48/facebook-48.png" style="vertical-align:middle" class="pic"/><a href="https://www.facebook.com/luca.fraser.9" target="_blank"><span class="marginLeft">Facebook</span></a></li>
      <li><img src="lucafraserProject/images/48x48/twitter-48.png" style="vertical-align:middle" class="pic"/><a href="https://twitter.com/xDivooo" target="_blank"><span class="marginLeft">Twitter</span></a></li>
      <li><img src="lucafraserProject/images/48x48/googleplus-48.png" style="vertical-align:middle" class="pic"/><a href="https://plus.google.com/101233334966337926037/posts" target="_blank"><span class="marginLeft">Google+</span></a></li>
      <li><img src="lucafraserProject/images/48x48/email-48.png" style="vertical-align:middle" class="pic"/><a href="mailto:lucaf1997@gmail.com" target="_blank"><span class="marginLeft">Gmail</span></a></li>
      <li><img src="lucafraserProject/images/48x48/instagram-48.png" style="vertical-align:middle" class="pic"/><a href="https://instagram.com/lucafraser16" target="_blank"><span class="marginLeft">Instagram</span></a></li>
      <li><img src="lucafraserProject/images/48x48/youtube-48.png" style="vertical-align:middle" class="pic"/><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUOgvY0q2C-GUOLVEhk5RbA" target="_blank"><span class="marginLeft">YouTube</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="widespace"></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright © Luca Fraser. Alle rechten voorbehouden.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go like this `parent:hover child {opacity:0.3;}`

here is the code [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNObdp).

Answer (score 4):

As you mentioned you know html and css please add class on links parent i.e ul see below example

```
<ul class="side-links">
```

then use below css in style file

```
.side-links li:hover{ opacity:0.3}
```

Done

Comment: Okay it's working right now, I have added your code! Thank you very much! One more question.. My text used to change when I hover over it but the text it's opacity changes like the image, how can I get it back to hover over = bold text?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the hover effect when you hover over the `a` or the `.pic` apply it when you hover over their containing `li` element.

```
#menuRechts li:hover .pic{
    opacity:0.3
}
#menuRechts li:hover a{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always make us of css pseudo classes

```
img:hover{

 opacity : 0.5;
}
```

this will decrease the opacity of every image by 50% , you can use any html element,css class or id instead of img

you can give any value between 0-1 
1 being total visible and 0 being totally transparent

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS:

```
#menuRechts li:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
```

}

and remove the .pic:hover code. This will make the entire LI element fade out, since it contains both the image and the text, theres no need to do both things separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to this code...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

img:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Image Transparency</h1>
<img src="klematis.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis">
<img src="klematis2.jpg" width="150" height="113" alt="klematis">

<p><b>Note:</b> In IE, a !DOCTYPE must be added for 
the :hover selector to work on other elements than the a element.</p>
</body>
</html>
```